# Can't upload files through Sitecore CMS

Tags: sitecore-client

I'm a newbie at Sitecore and recently took over the position where I have to make some changes in Sitecore website such as updating texts and uploading attachment. I tried to look at existing products and follow folder path to upload new attachment files but I can't do it because

1. I can't find one folder in path for ex)
   \examplefolder\upload\anotherexmaple is where other files are located at but I can't find that upload folder
2. When I tried to make new folder and upload files and use it instead, nothing happens when I click on Upload button in media library

When I hover over the upload button,
long string shows at the bottom of browser ends with

```
database=master#readonly=0&db=master#
```

Does this mean I don't have access to do this?

Sitecore version is 6.4.1

Comment: Check your browser, this old Sitecore version use a Adobe Flash component for uploading media files. For clarity default it upload the file to the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So a few things going on. First, and probably most importantly, your version of Sitecore will not be fully functional on most modern browsers. Specifically if you're using Chrome.

For reference information, see: [Sitecore does not work in Chrome 37 and later](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/581527)

Now, unless you have developer access to your solution (doesn't sound to me like you have), you will not be able to implement any of the proposed solutions offered in this article. You would need to request this from whoever maintains your solution. Switching to Internet Explorer might solve some of it for you, I'm not sure.

Don't worry too much about finding an "upload" folder - the CMS should be configured for you. Usually you will find some sort of folder structure under "Media Library" and, as appropriate, you will upload your images to there. Upload fails for you - most likely - because of the above limitations of Chrome.

[image]